# Use more specific rewrite tool on htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want replace my link as follows

> www.site.com?action&MasterKategori=Music&kategori=Pop&SubKategori=Western

by

> www.site.com/Music/Pop/Western

I use this script

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) index.php?action&m=$1&k=$2&s=$3

It works! But changes my web site preference, all included files (css,js) are rewritten too when the URL is clicked.

How can I stop that happening?

Comment: Use `base` tag: `<base href="http://www.yourdomain.com/" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rewrite conditions to tell the rule not to match URIs that correspond to actual files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) index.php?action&m=$1&k=$2&s=$3
```

Comment: it works but still change my web preference replace included file(css,js,etc)

Comment: How can it work, and do nothing? If the above is capturing requests for files, your file urls are wrong. Nor sure what "web preference" means.

Comment: @AD7six the web showing good on home page like www.site.com but when clicking link which have rewrite with Htacces it be lost all included file *sorry for bad english

Comment: You have described one problem (and have received an answer to that question) and now have another different problem - look at the requested url for your css/js files when it "doesn't work". You are likely requesting /current/url/css/file.css - which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you can add any extension you want to the third line) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|ico)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+) index.php?action&m=$1&k=$2&s=$3 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following line before RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
```